# How can i get my facebook social likes back

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I recently migrated a website from HTTP to HTTPS. After the migration, all the facebook likes disappeared. How can I get facebook likes back?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can´t just migrate the likes, it´s a new URL with https. What you can try is to put the old http URL in the og:url parameter though.